# how to fix the function multi_compare

Tags: python, function

```
import re
def multi_compare(pat_file : open, text_file1 : open, text_file2 : open) -> [(int,str,str)]:
   result = []
   m = []
   for p in pat_file:
       m = re.compile(p.rstrip())
       for num, line in enumerate(text_file1):
           for num2, line2 in enumerate(text_file2):
               if (m.match(line) != m.match(line2) and num == num2):
                   result.append((num,line,line2))
   return result
```

I am writing a function called `multi_compare`, that takes three open files as arguments: the first file contains some number of regular expression patterns, the second and third files contain some number of lines of text. This function returns a list of 3-tuples. Each returned 3-tuple represents a line number and one line from each file (the one with that line number), for which the line from the first file matched different patterns than the line from the second file. The list should show these line numbers in ascending order (which can be done without sorting).

For example if the files pats1.txt, texts1a.txt and texts1b.txt store the information shown below, calling

```
 multi_compare(open('pats1.txt'), open('texts1a.txt'), open('texts1b.txt'))
```

returns the following list:

```
[(2, '!aaab', '666b6'), (3, 'ambulance7', '7a')]
```

[image]

my code does not seem to work. can someone help me to fix my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your code here  if (m.match(line) != m.match(line2) and num == num2):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution to this issue.  The nested loop structure is kind of awful, so you want to unwind it as shown below.  The essential issue that you had, as pointed out by R. Kumar, was that you were testing the return from match (which is an object or None) instead of its boolean representation:

```
import re

def multi_compare(patterns_file, text_file1, text_file2):
    patterns = [ re.compile(x.strip()) for x in patterns_file ]
    matches1, matches2 = [], []

    for line in text_file1:
        # associate the line with its match array
        # where the match array is a list of booleans
        # that represent whether the line matched one of the specified patterns
        line = line.strip()
        matches = [ bool(x.match(line)) for x in patterns ]
        matches1.append((line, matches))

    for line in text_file2:
        line = line.strip()
        matches = [ bool(x.match(line)) for x in patterns ]
        matches2.append((line, matches))

    # compare the two text files by comparing the matches from each line
    for i, ((line1, match1), (line2, match2)) in enumerate(zip(matches1, matches2), 1):
        if match1 != match2:
            yield i, line1, line2

for x in multi_compare(open('pats1.txt', 'r'), open('text1a.txt', 'r'), open('text1b.txt', 'r')):
    print x
```

Comment: I tried it and I get the output  <generator object multi_compare at 0x01970690>

Comment: Yeah, it returns as generator.  You can convert it to a list with the for loop like shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, from what I've gathered is that you want to check if each line at matching line numbers from `text_file1` and `text_file2` match any of the patterns. However you want to determine if one line matches a pattern while the other doesn't. `True and False` or `False and True`. If you get a match then ignore all other patterns.

```
import re

def multi_compare(pat_file : open, text_file1 : open, text_file2 : open) -> [(int,str,str)]:
    result = []

    # create a list of each compiled pattern
    patterns = [ re.compile(p.rstrip()) for p in pat_file ]

    # iterate through each line number and lines
    for num, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(text_file1, text_file2), 1):
        line1, line2 = line1.strip(), line2.strip()
        for m in patterns:
            # compare matches - True, False or False, True will append
            if bool(m.match(line1)) != bool(m.match(line2)):
                result.append((num, line1, line2))
                # Found a match so exit inner for loop to stop matching again
                break

    return result

res = multi_compare(open('pats1.txt'), open('texts1a.txt'), open('texts1b.txt')) 
print(res)

# Output
[(2, '!aaab', '666b6'), (3, 'ambulance7', '7a')]
```

If you change to `result.append((num, m.pattern, line1, line2))` and remove the `break` you can see what pattern was matched with each line.

```
[(2, '.*\\d$', '!aaab', '666b6'), (3, '[a-z]', 'ambulance7', '7a'), (3, '.*b', 'ambulance7', '7a'), (3, '.*\\d$', 'ambulance7', '7a')]
```

Comment: the (4, '4b17', '666b6') should not be included

Comment: @zhangdi I don't understand how you get `(2, '!aaab', '666b6')` then?

Comment: I mean the correct answer is [(2, '!aaab', '666b6'), (3, 'ambulance7', '7a')]

Comment: Yes, but following the logic provided. either `'!aaab'` or `'666b6'` should match `'[a-z]'` but not both, and neither match.

Comment: I am also really confused,  I am not sure how to get rid of the last one

Comment: Updated answer. I believe this is what you were going for.